# Would an enhancement MOSFET work if there were no minority charge carriers in the substrate?

Tags: nmos, pmos

In an enhancement MOSFET, the channel is created from the minority charge carriers in the subtrate, attracted by the gate polarisation.

Consider for example an NMOS. The substrate is P. If the P substrate is of extremely good quality then there is no minority charge carrier. Thus, it will be impossible to create an N-channel.

Do enhancement MOSFETs only work because of "non perfect" substrate, that is, because there are residual minority charge carriers in the substrate? Would it work if there were no minority charge carriers?

Comment: *the P substrate is of extremely good quality* What does "extremely good" mean? Realize that in case of an NMOS, the voltage at the gate **will** pull electrons from the P-type substrate to form the channel. If there are no minority carriers, how can the silicon be P-type?

Comment: extremely good is meaning : "no defect", thus no minority charge carrier.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie : P-type is meaning more holes, which is majority charge carrier : theoretically speaking, the P-type does not need minority charge carrier

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie : what you write is not true. in a (enriched) NMOS, you apply VGS>0 : the electron minority charge carrier are *attracted* by the gate (not pulled as you write).

Comment: *extremely good is meaning : "no defect", thus no minority charge carrier.* I doubt that defects are needed to create minority carriers. In doped silicon minority carriers are generated randomly.

Comment: *the electron minority charge carrier are attracted by the gate (not pulled as you write)* Read carefully: I was talking about **electrons**. If the gate has a positive voltage relative to the substrate, electrons are pulled to that gate.

Comment: sorry, there was a misunderstanding from me for the word (to pull) : I thought it was meaning the opposite to attract. Apparently, to pull is meaning to attract, so we agree each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's suppose that the P substrate is of extremely good quality : then there is no minority charge carrier.

This cannot happen. Semiconductors follow the law of mass action

$$n_i=pn$$

That is the product of the electron and hole concentrations equals the intrinsic concentration. A semiconductor cannot have no minority carriers. Quality of the semiconductor is not a factor here. You can degenerately dope the semiconductor, which allows your material to break this law, but you will still have some minority carriers. At least for as long as you have a doped semiconductor, and not a metal alloy.

The existence of two types of carriers is an important property of a semiconductor. If you are talking about a material with only one type it sounds like you are describing a metal, not a semiconductor.

> In enhancement mosfet, the channel is created from the minority charge carriers in the substrate, attracted by the gate polarisation.

But if we assume for a minute there is a sufficiently low number of minority carriers for what you are asking. Attraction of minority carriers is not the only way to charge the channel. You can instead get carriers from generation. Generation is a much slower process, but it plays a role which you can demonstrate in MOSCAP C-V curves if you vary the measurement frequency.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you for having explained. So, from your kind explanation, I would think that "MESFET" would be less performant at low temperature than MOSFET, because of presence of metal in MESFET.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will get charge carrier injection from the degenerately doped source and drain contacts. This is part of the reason MOSFETs still work at 20 K despite the fact that the minority carrier concentration is effectively zero. Here is an example of MOSFETs and other power devices still working down to 20 K:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8854889